# SQL Alternative to left outer join

Tags: sql, firebird

Is this a good alternative to LEFT OUTER JOIN, performance-wise? Is it the best?

```
 SELECT a.PRODUCT_ID
    ,a.PROD_NAME
    ,a.PRODUCTTYPE_ID
    ,a.SUPPLIER_ID
    ,t.PRODTYPE_NAME
    ,s."NAME" SUPPLIER_NAME
FROM PRODUCT a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NULL PRODUCTTYPE_ID
        ,NULL PRODTYPE_NAME
    FROM rdb$database

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PRODUCTTYPE_ID
        ,PRODTYPE_NAME
    FROM PRODUCTTYPE
    ) t
    ON (t.PRODUCTTYPE_ID = a.PRODUCTTYPE_ID) OR (t.PRODUCTTYPE_ID IS NULL AND a.PRODUCTTYPE_ID IS NULL)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NULL SUPPLIER_ID
        ,NULL "NAME"
    FROM rdb$database

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUPPLIER_ID
        ,"NAME"
    FROM SUPPLIER
    ) s
    ON (s.SUPPLIER_ID = a.SUPPLIER_ID) OR (s.SUPPLIER_ID IS NULL AND a.SUPPLIER_ID IS NULL)
```

Index on PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCTTYPE_ID, SUPPLIER_ID in Table PRODUCT and their respective tables by virtue of Primary Key and Foreign Keys

Comment: Can you post the alternative query which utilizes the left outer join? Have you tried running any performance timings or looked at the execution plan of the queries?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative to good old `left join`? Do you have some kind of performance issue? Do you have reason to believe `left join` is the cause?

Comment: Keys do not always create indexes (depends on things like dbms etc), and any indexes they do create may not be good for the query you're executing. Unions are generally NOT a good alternative. Need to know more about what problems you're having. I'm more versed with sql server, though.

Comment: I don't understand -- is the query you are showing the non-left join one?  It must be because it is using inner joins.

Comment: I might be guilty of over-generalization here. There is actually another statement I have in the system that is my actual concern but have the same general statement.

Comment: Performance timing are not helpful at this stage as the tables are sparsely populated. But I am anticipating circumstances when records start reaching tens of thousands. I have seen how LEFT JOIN performs poorly at this level.

Comment: @Nikki9696 In Firebird constraints like primary key, foreign key, unique key, etc all create an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No!

You should use `left join`.  Here are some reasons why your method is (in almost all likelihood) going to be worse:

- You are doing multiple joins instead of a single join.  A single join should be faster.
- You have `or` in the `on` clause.  Oy!  That's a performance killer.
- The use of `union all` *before* the join makes using indexes much more difficult.  And statistics are likely to be off (although I don't know if Firebird uses statistics to optimize queries).
- Your complicated query is less likely to use indexes.

A simple `left join` should use indexes and have much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the following query will give you the same functionality as the one you show then use it instead

```
SELECT a.PRODUCT_ID, a.PROD_NAME, a.PRODUCTTYPE_ID, a.SUPPLIER_ID , 
       t.PRODTYPE_NAME, s."NAME" SUPPLIER_NAME 
FROM PRODUCT a
left join PRODUCTTYPE P ON P.PRODUCTTYPE_ID=a.PRODUCTTYPE_ID 
left join SUPPLIER S ON s.SUPPLIER_ID=a.SUPPLIER_ID
```

You can see you don't have the union (or even UNION ALL which you should have used) -- so this will be faster.